# pip install "python.exe has stopped working" error

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

Whenever I run pip install BeautifulSoup mrjob pattern seaborn pyquery on command line windows 10, I get "python.exe has stopped working".
I have tried reinstalling python but it didn't help.
Anybody has a solution for this problem.
I am using Anaconda for Windows(python 2.7).